# Synchronization of a directory in 2 systems using rsync

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface, rsync

I am using rsync to  copy the delta difference between the 2 systems. I want to use it in such a way it "synchronizes"  the both systems based on the timestamps. I mean to say if suppose I do rsync Host A to Host B. And some one modifies the file i.e being sent in Host B.In host A also some change may occur. Now if i rsync from Host A to Host B i wish to have a synchrony such that the file gets transferred to Host A the difference created by host b and also the it should get transferred to Host B the difference made. Is there any command?

Is it possible?
Kindly reply,
Thank u
Sindhu

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a job for [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).